# How can i use reduce or any other array method, to count and sum up specific properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, reduce

I try to learn more about the array methods and also working with objects. I come up with this dummy example that simulate an incoming data.

```
    const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Company 1',
    sales: 100,
    status: 'win',
    brand: 'dell',
    year: 2020,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Company 2',
    sales: 300,
    status: 'lost',
    brand: 'dell',
    year: 2020,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Company 3',
    sales: 600,
    status: 'pending',
    brand: 'acer',
    year: 2021,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Company 3',
    sales: 800,
    status: 'pending',
    brand: 'lenovo',
    year: 2021,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Company 4',
    sales: 400,
    status: 'lost',
    brand: 'apple',
    year: 2020,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Company 1',
    sales: 1000,
    status: 'win',
    brand: 'apple',
    year: 2020,
  },
]
```

I would like to manipulate the information so i could come up with a new array like this:

```
    const projects = [
  {
    period: 2020,
    uniqueCompanies: 3,
    totalProjects: 4,
    totalSales: 1800,
    winStatus: 2,
    lostStatus: 2,
    winConversion: 0.5,
    lostConversion: 0.5,
    brands: [
      {
        brandName: 'dell',
        winProjects: 1,
        conversion: 0.25,
      },
      {
        brandName: 'apple',
        winProjects: 1,
        conversion: 0.25,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    period: 2021,
    ....
  }
]
```

I almost succeeded, but i can't reduce the brands array to the desire structure.

```
      const reduceData = data.reduce((acc, project) => {
  const { year, name, status, sales, brand } = project;

  if (!acc[year]) {
    acc[year] = {
      companies: new Set(),
      totalProjects: 0,
      totalSales: 0,
      winStatus: 0,
      lostStatus: 0,
      winConversion: 0,
      lostConversion: 0,
      brands: [],
    };
  }

  acc[year].companies.add(brand);
  acc[year].uniqueCompanies = [...acc[year].companies].length;
  acc[year].totalProjects = (acc[year].totalProjects || 0) + 1;
  acc[year].totalSales = acc[year].totalSales += sales;
  acc[year].winStatus =
    status === 'win' ? acc[year].winStatus + 1 : acc[year].winStatus;
  acc[year].lostStatus = acc[year].totalProjects - acc[year].winStatus;
  acc[year].winConversion = acc[year].winStatus / acc[year].totalProjects;
  acc[year].lostConversion = acc[year].lostStatus / acc[year].totalProjects;

  acc[year].brands.push({
    brandName: brand,
    totalSales: sales,
  });

  return acc;
}, {})
```

Please help me understand the logic of it!

Comment: create an object in this step `if (!acc[year]) acc[year] = {period:year, brands: []}` and push to the brands array. finally take the `Object.values(newReduceArr)` . you can manipulate the object and add fields however you like

Comment: Thank @cmgchess for your suggestion. So after the reduce method i create a new object where i extract the values and manipulate those ?

Comment: you can do that inside the reduce itself for example if you need to add the fields such as `uniqueCompanies` , `totalProjects`... etc

Comment: @cmgchess, i've update my initial attempt. I'm stuck in the part where i want to count the unique occurence of the company name. I thought of a possible option to create an empty array inside the accumulator and then push all the values for the name property, and then maybe try to extract the unique count with the Set method.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/Lwv8Rk not sure the format but you can covert set to array and get length

Comment: Yes, i was thinking of that as a solution. The only downfall is that you first need to create a new array with all the unique values and then add a new key that counts the unique values. Thaks for you solution. I will continue with the rest of structure, and hope to get to the desired shape.

Comment: I've update it my code. Can you please give me some guidence regarding the last piece of the puzzle :)